# gtksharpglue-2 not found when running Gtk# program on .NET

Tags: .net, gtk#

*This is on a different machine than the one that my [other recent Gtk# question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32039821/error-cs0246-when-trying-to-use-gtk) applies to.*

I am trying to run a Gtk# program on a Windows 7 x64 computer with all .NETs 1.0 to 4.0 installed. (I have been using Gtk# on this computer in the past, but more than a year ago for the last time.)

- I have downloaded and installed Gtk# 2.12.26 by using the installer package from the [Mono website](http://www.mono-project.com/download/#download-win).
- I have verified that the bin directory of that Gtk# installation is on my search path.<sup>1</sup>
- Using [SharpDevelop](http://www.sharpdevelop.com), I have created a .NET console project.
- I have added references to atk-sharp, gdk-sharp, glib-sharp, gtk-sharp, and Mono.Cairo.
- I have added some minimal code (`Application.Init();`, creation and display of a new window).
- When I run the application, the following exception is thrown:

  ```
  System.TypeInitializationException: Der Typeninitialisierer für "Gtk.Container" hat eine Ausnahme verursacht. ---> System.DllNotFoundException: Die DLL "gtksharpglue-2": Die angegebene Prozedur wurde nicht gefunden. (Ausnahme von HRESULT: 0x8007007F) kann nicht geladen werden.
     bei Gtk.Container.gtksharp_gtk_container_get_focus_child_offset()
     bei Gtk.Container..cctor()
     --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
     bei Gtk.Container..ctor(IntPtr raw)
     bei Gtk.Bin..ctor(IntPtr raw)
     bei Gtk.Window..ctor(WindowType type)
     bei Gtk.Window..ctor(String title)
     bei GtkSharpTest.Program.Main(String[] args) in ...\GtkSharpTest\Program.cs:Zeile 21.
  ```

The crucial bit of information seems to be:

> System.DllNotFoundException: Die DLL "gtksharpglue-2": Die angegebene Prozedur wurde nicht gefunden. (Ausnahme von HRESULT: 0x8007007F) kann nicht geladen werden.

meaning

> System.DllNotFoundException: Unable to load DLL "gtksharpglue-2": The specified procedure could not be found. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007007F)

A file named `gtksharpglue-2.dll` is located in the Gtk# bin directory that is on the system search path. Notably, my local [Mono](http://www.mono-project.com/) installation has an older version of that file, but even if I replace the file in the Mono installation with the newer version, the message remains. None of Mono's installation directories is on my search path, anyway.

**How can I fix this, and how can I make sure non-tech-savvy users of my Gtk# program will not run into the same issue?**

<sup>1</sup>: Remarkably, the bin directory was *not* automatically added to the search path by the installer package (either that, or [the search path had become too long once again](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4405091/how-avoid-over-populate-path-environment-variable-in-windows) and thus didn't work as desired, not sure any more); I had to manually edit the search path. In any case, *before* I had done so, `libglib-2.0-0.dll` was the file reported to be missing. *After* I had edited the search path, that file apparently could be loaded, just `gtksharpglue-2.dll` cannot.

Comment: What's the downvote for?

Comment: Is your program targetting .NET 4.5? Have you tried compiling outside SharpDevelop? http://www.mono-project.com/docs/gui/gtksharp/hello-world/